# UWP: Cannot convert from 'int' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty"

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am developing a UWP App where I want to bind some properties the code behind. Currently, I have the following:

Sample.xaml

```
<Grid>
  <Border Margin="0">
  <controls:Carousel x:Name="CarouselControl"
              InvertPositive="True"
              ItemDepth="300"
              ItemMargin="{Binding ItemsMargin}"
              ItemRotationX="0"
              ItemRotationY="45"
              ItemRotationZ ="0"
              Orientation="Horizontal"
              SelectedIndex="4">
    <controls:Carousel.EasingFunction>
      <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
    </controls:Carousel.EasingFunction>
    <controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Image Width="200"
              Height="200"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
              Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"
              Stretch="Uniform" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
  </controls:Carousel>
</Border>
```

The code behind

```
  public sealed partial class Sample
  {
      private int itemsMargin;
      public int ItemsMargin
    {
        get => this.itemsMargin;
        set => this.SetValue(this.itemsMargin, value);
    }
  }
```

I get an error on this.SetValue that Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty'. Any help in understanding this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DependencyObject.SetValue Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.setvalue?view=winrt-19041) requires a [DependencyProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyproperty?view=winrt-19041) and an object as parameters. Int is not a DependencyProperty.

Use the following code instead:

```
  private int itemsMargin;
    public int ItemsMargin
    {
        get => this.itemsMargin;
        set => this.itemsMargin = value;
    }
```